# Why is my solution unable to pass Leetcode Word-break question

Tags: python, algorithm, testing, recursion, dynamic-programming

My solution doesn't work when I click submit since it fails some cases, however when I run those very same test cases, under custom test case it works. Could someone help me figure out why?

Here is my solution

```
class Solution:

storage = set()
def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
    
    if not s or s in self.storage:
        return True
    
    for word in wordDict:
        if word in s:
            lst = s.split(word, 1)
            if self.wordBreak(lst[0], wordDict) and self.wordBreak(lst[1], wordDict):
                self.storage.add(s)
                return True
    
    return False
```

Here is the test case

"a"
["b"]

Here is a picture of it not working in submit but working under custom test cases.
[image]

Comment: Maybe it's because you created `storage` outside the function; so it also contains words from previous test cases. Maybe the system first tested your code with a different `wordDict`, possibly `'a'` being one of them, so your `storage` still contains this `'a'`.

Comment: Even if you fix that problem, your algorithm will be too slow to pass all tests.

Comment: Are we deemed to guess the Leetcode problem ??

Comment: Yeah storage was the problem. Looks like I'll also need to rewrite my algorithm since it's not efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The issue with my code was that I had initialized list outside of the function, so it was updated every time function was called, whereas I wanted it to be empty every time function is called. So I emptied at the end of function.

If you could give the problem statement, it would be easier to figure what the actual problem is.

Comment: This is the question. I think I can solve the problem even if we don't know the exact test cases that are interfering.  https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/amazon/80/dynamic-programming/2997/

Answer (score 1):

It fails on those test cases because `storage` will not be reset to an empty set between consecutive runs of tests, and so it will have false information about a next test case.

However, even if you would manage that `storage` such that it would be reset on every test, you would bump into a time out message on the more complex test cases. So you'll need a more efficient algorithm.

To make sure your code works, I would suggest to pay attention to the following test cases:

```
"fohhemkkaecojceoaejkkoedkofhmohkcjmkggcmnami"
["kfomka","hecagbngambii","anobmnikj","c","nnkmfelneemfgcl","ah","bgomgohl","lcbjbg","ebjfoiddndih","hjknoamjbfhckb","eioldlijmmla","nbekmcnakif","fgahmihodolmhbi","gnjfe","hk","b","jbfgm","ecojceoaejkkoed","cemodhmbcmgl","j","gdcnjj","kolaijoicbc","liibjjcini","lmbenj","eklingemgdjncaa","m","hkh","fblb","fk","nnfkfanaga","eldjml","iejn","gbmjfdooeeko","jafogijka","ngnfggojmhclkjd","bfagnfclg","imkeobcdidiifbm","ogeo","gicjog","cjnibenelm","ogoloc","edciifkaff","kbeeg","nebn","jdd","aeojhclmdn","dilbhl","dkk","bgmck","ohgkefkadonafg","labem","fheoglj","gkcanacfjfhogjc","eglkcddd","lelelihakeh","hhjijfiodfi","enehbibnhfjd","gkm","ggj","ag","hhhjogk","lllicdhihn","goakjjnk","lhbn","fhheedadamlnedh","bin","cl","ggjljjjf","fdcdaobhlhgj","nijlf","i","gaemagobjfc","dg","g","jhlelodgeekj","hcimohlni","fdoiohikhacgb","k","doiaigclm","bdfaoncbhfkdbjd","f","jaikbciac","cjgadmfoodmba","molokllh","gfkngeebnggo","lahd","n","ehfngoc","lejfcee","kofhmoh","cgda","de","kljnicikjeh","edomdbibhif","jehdkgmmofihdi","hifcjkloebel","gcghgbemjege","kobhhefbbb","aaikgaolhllhlm","akg","kmmikgkhnn","dnamfhaf","mjhj","ifadcgmgjaa","acnjehgkflgkd","bjj","maihjn","ojakklhl","ign","jhd","kndkhbebgh","amljjfeahcdlfdg","fnboolobch","gcclgcoaojc","kfokbbkllmcd","fec","dljma","noa","cfjie","fohhemkka","bfaldajf","nbk","kmbnjoalnhki","ccieabbnlhbjmj","nmacelialookal","hdlefnbmgklo","bfbblofk","doohocnadd","klmed","e","hkkcmbljlojkghm","jjiadlgf","ogadjhambjikce","bglghjndlk","gackokkbhj","oofohdogb","leiolllnjj","edekdnibja","gjhglilocif","ccfnfjalchc","gl","ihee","cfgccdmecem","mdmcdgjelhgk","laboglchdhbk","ajmiim","cebhalkngloae","hgohednmkahdi","ddiecjnkmgbbei","ajaengmcdlbk","kgg","ndchkjdn","heklaamafiomea","ehg","imelcifnhkae","hcgadilb","elndjcodnhcc","nkjd","gjnfkogkjeobo","eolega","lm","jddfkfbbbhia","cddmfeckheeo","bfnmaalmjdb","fbcg","ko","mojfj","kk","bbljjnnikdhg","l","calbc","mkekn","ejlhdk","hkebdiebecf","emhelbbda","mlba","ckjmih","odfacclfl","lgfjjbgookmnoe","begnkogf","gakojeblk","bfflcmdko","cfdclljcg","ho","fo","acmi","oemknmffgcio","mlkhk","kfhkndmdojhidg","ckfcibmnikn","dgoecamdliaeeoa","ocealkbbec","kbmmihb","ncikad","hi","nccjbnldneijc","hgiccigeehmdl","dlfmjhmioa","kmff","gfhkd","okiamg","ekdbamm","fc","neg","cfmo","ccgahikbbl","khhoc","elbg","cbghbacjbfm","jkagbmfgemjfg","ijceidhhajmja","imibemhdg","ja","idkfd","ndogdkjjkf","fhic","ooajkki","fdnjhh","ba","jdlnidngkfffbmi","jddjfnnjoidcnm","kghljjikbacd","idllbbn","d","mgkajbnjedeiee","fbllleanknmoomb","lom","kofjmmjm","mcdlbglonin","gcnboanh","fggii","fdkbmic","bbiln","cdjcjhonjgiagkb","kooenbeoongcle","cecnlfbaanckdkj","fejlmog","fanekdneoaammb","maojbcegdamn","bcmanmjdeabdo","amloj","adgoej","jh","fhf","cogdljlgek","o","joeiajlioggj","oncal","lbgg","elainnbffk","hbdi","femcanllndoh","ke","hmib","nagfahhljh","ibifdlfeechcbal","knec","oegfcghlgalcnno","abiefmjldmln","mlfglgni","jkofhjeb","ifjbneblfldjel","nahhcimkjhjgb","cdgkbn","nnklfbeecgedie","gmllmjbodhgllc","hogollongjo","fmoinacebll","fkngbganmh","jgdblmhlmfij","fkkdjknahamcfb","aieakdokibj","hddlcdiailhd","iajhmg","jenocgo","embdib","dghbmljjogka","bahcggjgmlf","fb","jldkcfom","mfi","kdkke","odhbl","jin","kcjmkggcmnami","kofig","bid","ohnohi","fcbojdgoaoa","dj","ifkbmbod","dhdedohlghk","nmkeakohicfdjf","ahbifnnoaldgbj","egldeibiinoac","iehfhjjjmil","bmeimi","ombngooicknel","lfdkngobmik","ifjcjkfnmgjcnmi","fmf","aoeaa","an","ffgddcjblehhggo","hijfdcchdilcl","hacbaamkhblnkk","najefebghcbkjfl","hcnnlogjfmmjcma","njgcogemlnohl","ihejh","ej","ofn","ggcklj","omah","hg","obk","giig","cklna","lihaiollfnem","ionlnlhjckf","cfdlijnmgjoebl","dloehimen","acggkacahfhkdne","iecd","gn","odgbnalk","ahfhcd","dghlag","bchfe","dldblmnbifnmlo","cffhbijal","dbddifnojfibha","mhh","cjjol","fed","bhcnf","ciiibbedklnnk","ikniooicmm","ejf","ammeennkcdgbjco","jmhmd","cek","bjbhcmda","kfjmhbf","chjmmnea","ifccifn","naedmco","iohchafbega","kjejfhbco","anlhhhhg"]
```

And:

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab"
["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa"]
```

I'll leave a hint for finding a better algorithm:

> memoization (dynamic programming)

Comment: Yeah you are correct that my solution didn't pass due to time complexity. My solution works by searching the wordDict for a word that is in the string. Once it finds a word, it recursively runs the algorithm on the left and right side with of course `storage` being used for memoization. The official leetcode solution works by incrementing through the string until it finds a word in wordDict. Therefore my solution isn't good for large wordDict while the official solution works better.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but there could be a case where my algorithm works better if the wordDict doesn't have many strings but each string is very long. For example `"a" * 2 ** 100, ["a" * 2 ** 50]`

Comment: actually nvm, you're right.